# persisting breakpoints in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, dojo, debugging, web-inspector

How does one get Safari's debugger to persist a breakpoint across a page refresh?  I'm trying to debug code that's executed onLoad, so I don't have time to set the breakpoint before the code is executed, and when I refresh the page after setting the breakpoint, the breakpoint is lost.

(The code in question is in a Dojo widget, so it's loaded via an XHR, if that matters.)

Comment: I know that 'works for me' isn't helpful, but I can't seem to reproduce this. You could try putting the `debugger` command in your code, or take a look at the [Safari Reference Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about the `debugger` command, thanks!  Add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm not sure that `debugger` is a javascript function in general or specific to firebug, that's why I haven't answered as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a javascript statement which might be of use to you called `debugger`. While this function is poorly documented, it usually triggers your browser's built-in debugger. The only note I've really found on the statement [is this](http://www.brokenbuild.com/blog/2006/12/07/javascript-debugger-statement/).

> Javascript as a language spec does not have a debug statement, however all implementations do implement a debugger statement.

Although, I am not sure why your breakpoints are not persisting. I do not have Safari available to test, but Chrome (which is also based on Webkit) does seem to be persisting breakpoints correctly.

**EDIT**

I managed to find [documentation for the `debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement, but it is not very descriptive:

> Invokes any available debugging functionality. If no debugging functionality is available, this statement has no effect.